# A custom attribute for setting whether a textbox is editable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to setup a custom attribute in C# to set whether a business object property is editable, eventually enabling or disabling ReadOnly a textbox in XAML. Since (I thought) IsEditable was already implemented in System.Windows.Controls, i thought this would work:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EditableAttribute : Attribute
{
    public EditableAttribute(bool isEditable)
    {
        this.ReadOnly = !isEditable;

    }
    public virtual bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
}
```

Well, go figure, it doesn't. I set [Editable(false)] to a string in an object and it is still editable. I have a feeling I'm not even close. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I am aware this can be setup as a style in xaml, but for this case it needs to be in the business object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BindingDecoratorBase](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/04/wpf-custom-binding-class) to use custom binding and use an attribute.

The following code is just me modifying my code in my project that uses [custom validation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39198/Automatically-validating-business-entities-in-WPF) .  It probably should be refractored.

```
public interface IEditatble
{
    void SetValue(Control sender, DependencyProperty property);
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EditableAttribute : Attribute, IEditatble
{
    public EditableAttribute(bool isEditable)
    {
        this.ReadOnly = !isEditable;

    }
    public virtual bool ReadOnly { get; set; }

    public void SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Control sender, System.Windows.DependencyProperty property)
    {
        sender.SetValue(property, this.ReadOnly);
    }
}
```

You can create a custom binding:

```
 public class ReadonlyBinding : BindingDecoratorBase
 {
    private DependencyProperty _targetProperty = null;
    public ReadonlyBinding()
    : base()
    {
        Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        // Get the binding expression
        object bindingExpression = base.ProvideValue(provider);

        // Bound items
        DependencyObject targetObject;
       
        // Try to get the bound items
        if (TryGetTargetItems(provider, out targetObject, out _targetProperty))
        {
            if (targetObject is FrameworkElement)
            {
                // Get the element and implement datacontext changes
                FrameworkElement element = targetObject as FrameworkElement;
                element.DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(element_DataContextChanged);
            }
        }

        // Go on with the flow
        return bindingExpression;
    }

    void element_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        object datacontext = e.NewValue;
        if (datacontext != null && _targetProperty != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = datacontext.GetType().GetProperty(Binding.Path.Path);
            if (property != null)
            {
                var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(o => o is IEditatble).FirstOrDefault();
                if (attribute != null)
                {                        
                    Control cntrl = sender as Control;
                    ((IEditatble)attribute).SetValue(cntrl, _targetProperty);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
[Editable(true)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBox  IsReadOnly="{local:ReadonlyBinding Path=Name}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For your EditableAttribute to work, TextBox classes should use reflection on your model to check whether the attribute is set and set necessary properties. What I'm trying to say is that attribute is no more than metadata and it doesn't control the application workflow unless the application wishes so.

You could inherit from basic TextBox and insert necessary functionality though it is an overkill. You should just declare IsSomePropertyReadOnly variable and bind to it in TextBox.

Though if you're feeling really fancy, you could write some wrapper class like

```
public class ReadOrWriteText<T>
{
    private T _value;
    bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }

    public T Value 
    { 
       get { return _value; }
       set { if (IsReadOnly) return; _value = value; }
    }
}
```

and bind to it's IsReadOnly and Value properties. Though it is an overkill also.